# How to rename excel file name dynamically?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, expression, etl

I'm trying to change excel file dynamically whenever I run my job on date basis.

In connection string of excel connection manager i have tried:

```
"C:\ReportOutput" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()) ,2)+
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()),2)+
(DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) +"_withdata.xls"
```

But it is not working. Also in connection manager I have provided the file location. I want file to create and rename dynamically every time the job runs.

Comment: What does "but it not working" mean?   Do you get an error?

Answer (score 3):

I think that the main problem is that you missed the escape character, also you can use `DAY()`, `MONTH()`, `YEAR()` instead of `DATEPART()`:

```
"C:\\ReportOutput" + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(GetDate()) ,2) +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(GetDate()),2)+
(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(GetDate()) +"_withdata.xls"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need follow 2 steps to rename excel file name dynamically.

In 1st Step, Create 3 variables with String DataType

1. **OutputFolderPath**: This is Static variable in which we store the OutPut Folder Name (i.e.:C:\)
2. **Date_Time_Dynamic**:
   This is a Dynamic Variable used to Store the Date Time value (Eg : "20190909_114500" ) Calculated from GetDate() funcation using below Expression..

***With Time***: REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,50)GETDATE(),1,19),"-",""),":","")," ","_")
***Without Time***: REPLACE(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,50)GETDATE(),1,10),"-","")

3. **OutputFileFullPath**:
   This is an Important Dynamic Variable used in the Package to create and Output File dynamically with Date Time suffix to the Template File name done by File System Task.
   This file will passed dynamically to the Excel Destination connection in the Data Flow, to save the output.
   This variable value is Calculated using the below Expression..

   @[User::OutputFolderPath] + "ReportOutput_"+ @[User::Date_Time_Dynamic]+".xls"

e.g.: C:\ReportOutput_20190909_114500.xls - With Time
C:\ReportOutput_20190909.xls - Without Time 
**Note**: Need to add time as suffix. So,it will always create new file at destination folder.

In 2nd Step, make the Excel connection to the Excel File is dynamic, by assigning the ExcelFilePath to a Variable from Properties > Expressions as shown below...

ExcelFilePath = @[User::OutputFileFullPath]

[image]

Comment: Thanks JIKEN but I'm not able create new excel sheet dynamically every time i'm trying to run the package. It takes the file name with new date but doesn't create any file   @[User::OutputFile]+"ReportOutput_"+REPLACE(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,50)GETDATE(),1,10),"-","")+".xls" --i'm using this in Excel file path expression

Comment: @TirathSingh - Kindly check this [link](http://www.techbrothersit.com/2015/12/ssis-tutorial-part-17-create-excel-file.html?m=1). You need to use file system task to copy template file from template folder to destination folder.